# replacing the Win 8.1 disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop

The mother board on my out of warranty laptop running OEM Windows 8.1 died.  So I bought another of the exact same model laptop with OEM Windows 8.1.

I do not want to spend hours copying and files and re-installing and re-configuring my old software on my new computer.  Can I just put the hard disk from the old laptop into the new identical modeled laptop?

Will the be an OEM license issue with Windows 8.1?

Thanks

J.B.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the exact same hardware as your previous laptop, you would be able to do this.

You will likely have an activation problem. However, you have a valid licence for the machine you're using, which isn't tied to the hard drive. As such, you will likely need to reactivate (possibly using the automated telephone system), but it should be possible.

In a worst case scenario, you can simply put the previous hard drive back in and no harm would be done, although before attempting any of this I'd back up my data if it's at all possible, as it sounds like if it doesn't work for whatever reason you will want the data anyway.